# cypress wait for redirection after login

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, cypress, wait

I am testing a web app with cypress.

I sign in in my `beforeEach` function. Then, in my different tests, I begin with `cy.visit('mysite.com/url')`.

My problem is that after sign in, the website redirects to a specific page of the website. This redirection happens after the `cy.visit` of my tests. Therefore, my tests run on the redirection page, they fail.

The redirection seems to be not linked with any request I could wait for.

I end up with `cy.wait(3000)` but it is not very satisfying. My tests failed sometimes because the redirection might take more than 3 seconds. I do not want to increase that time because it would take too long to run my tests.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
while (!cy.url().eq('mysite.com/redirection-url')) {
  cy.wait(300);
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Cypress provides retry abilities on assertion. You can resolve the waiting issue for the redirection URL with the below change

```
cy.url().should('contain', '/redirection-url')
```

OR

```
cy.url().should('eq', 'mysite.com/redirection-url')
```

Here `should` assertion will wait till 4 seconds by default and retries `cy.url()`

You can change the default timeout by updating parameter in `cypress.json` file

```
{
  "defaultCommandTimeout": 30000
}
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Nice answer, but just wondering isn't the default command wait time is 4 seconds instead of 5 seconds?

Comment: You are right @konekoya  `defaultCommandTimeout` is 4 seconds. Updated the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.!

Comment: thanks ! To be complete, `cy.url` accept a `timeout` key in its `options` argument for assertions we've added to pass. No need to modify the `defaultCommandTimeout`.

Comment: @Gaut, but if you will call that function several times, it would be better to have it in confi instead of `options`. I guess.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin: First, I called this function only once after signin in my beforeEach function, I think doing otherwise leads to conception issue. Second, even if I call this function several times, modifying conf would lead to modify the comportement of each cypress function call, you don't want to do so if you can be more specific.

Answer (score 4):

If the redirect is to a different server, simply using cy.url does not work.
We solved the problem with the following code:

```
cy.origin('https://localhost:7256/',() => {
  cy.url().should(
  'contains',
  'account/login');
})
```

where `https://localhost:7256/` is the base URL of the server to which we are redirected.