# Cypress test setup for Azure AD B2C login with custom policy

Tags: reactjs, azure, cypress, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

## Setup

- Azure AD B2C with custom policies (B2C_1A_SIGNIN)
- React frontend
- MSAL to implement the authentication (@azure/msal-browser: 2.37.0, @azure/msal-react:1.5.7) - using loginRedirect() (no MFA)
- Cypress (v12.5.1) for e2e tests

## What I did

I implemented authentication for my frontend app via the MSAL library, created an app registration for my app, added the redirect URIs and the custom login policy. The whole login flow works pretty well, I get my token, everything is fine.

## The problem

I'm using cypress for e2e tests and now (since I implemented authentication) I have to update all of my tests of course, as all of my tests expect to be already logged in.

And this is the part where it gets tricky. If I get things right, the preferred way is to add a login() command to my cypress config, that does the whole login stuff only once before the tests are executed.

## What I tried so far

### 1. Acquiring a token non-interactively

I followed this guide https://blog.mechanicalrock.io/2022/08/08/azure-ad-authentication-cypress.html to request a token for my test user via api instead of interactively challenging the user for his credentials.

#### Default endpoint

At first I tested Microsofts default endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com via postman:

```
POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<b2cTenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/token
body: {
  grant_type:password
  client_id:<applicationId>
  client_secret:<clientSecret>
  scope:openid profile email
  username:<testUsername>
  password:<testUserPassword>
}
```

This worked and I got an Id-Token and an access token. Problem here is that this token does not work with my custom sign in policy.

#### Custom endpoint

So I tried the same for my custom policies endpoint:

```
POST: https://<b2cDomain>.b2clogin.com/<b2cdomain>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_SIGNIN/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=B2C_1A_SIGNIN
body: {
  grant_type:password
  client_id:<applicationId>
  client_secret:<clientSecret>
  scope:openid profile email
  username:<testUsername>
  password:<testUserPassword>
}
```

But for that request I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "AADB2C90055: The scope 'openid profile email' provided in request must specify a resource, such as 'https://example.com/calendar.read'.\r\nCorrelation ID: <someId> \r\nTimestamp: 2023-05-12 14:03:41Z\r\n"
}
```

I also tried it without a scope, but the endpoint does expect a scope. So either this way does not work with custom policies or I am doing something wrong.

### 2. Filling the login form via cypress

The second approach that I tried was to handle the real frontend sign in flow via cypress. But somehow it seems that cypress doesn't like the redirection way of signing in. I followed basically this guide https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/azure-active-directory-authentication which is not specialized on custom policies.

My latest testing code (including the tip to use cy.origin() from here [cypress wait for redirection after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64553275/cypress-wait-for-redirection-after-login)) was:

```
cy.visit('http://localhost:3000');
cy.origin(
'https://<b2cDomain>.b2clogin.com',
{
  args: {},
},
() => {
  cy.url().should('contain', 'https://<b2cDomain>.b2clogin.com');
  cy.get('input[id="signInName"]').type(Cypress.env('AZURE_TEST_USERNAME'), {
    log: false,
  });
  cy.get('input[id="password"]').type(Cypress.env('AZURE_TEST_PASSWORD'), {
    log: false,
  });
  cy.get('button[id="next"]').click();
}
);

// cy.wait(1000);
cy.url().should('contain', 'http://localhost:3000');
```

The thing that annoys me the most is, that the code seems to work (when looking at the execution video), but that the tests fail anyway. And they fail on a very early point. It seems to me that it's somehow an asynchronous problem. But anyway: the error message does not make any sense to me:

[image: Cypress error log]

Testing around made me feel that cypress does not properly handle the redirect, but I have no idea how it could work.

And now I don't know which approach is more promising. **I appreciate any hints or alternative solutions**.

Answer (score 2):

The guide you are following is for Azure AD but you are trying to implement a solution for Azure AD B2C. There is not an official guide for this on the Azure side, so I do not believe that this is "officially" supported. I'm less familiar with the Cypress configuration but there are some well-known issues with CORS handling in Cypress, which can trigger the "Cannot set property name of [object DOMException] which only has a getter." Cypress prevents cross-origin calls so you would need to use the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow to post user credentials to Azure and get the tokens. This would have limitations for your scenario though since the flow only works for local accounts in B2C where your users have registered with B2C using an email address or username. This [guide](https://www.eliostruyf.com/cypress-test-sharepoint-solution-azure-ad-secured-api/) provides an example of how to get the access token from Azure AD:

```js
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `https://login.microsoft.com/${config.tenant}/oauth2/token`,
```

One workaround just for testing is to set `chromeWebSecurity: false` in the `cypress.json` as referenced in [Getting "cannot set property name of which has only a getter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69006948/getting-cannot-set-property-name-of-which-has-only-a-getter)